Followup to earlier Eclipse/Egit question (a problem with resolving merge conflict
I asked about to how to use Eclipse/Egit to resolve merge conflicts earlier last week (Trying to understand the process of Resolving Merge Conflicts with Eclipse/egit), and since then I was able to successfully resolve merge conflicts a couple of times.
However, today, I ran into a problem... I don't really know why or what I did, and it is also a little difficult to explain what I am seeing.
I am working in a team environment, with multiple people working on the same files.
So I made some changes in my Java/Cucumber project locally, and tested the changes, and my changes worked.
I wanted to see if there would be merge conflicts, so I made a commit (my 1st commit for this branch).  Then I made a "temp" PR in Bitbucket, so that I could see whether it showed any conflicts, which it did, and I ran the 2 git bash commands that Bitbucket said to run, and after that Eclipse showed that there was a conflict in one file (this was a Java files with the step definitions) and had 4 other files in the staged pane, so I then deleted the PR in Bitbucket.
So then I wanted to try to resolve the conflicts, so I right-clicked on the file that had conflicts and selected Merge Tool, and the 2 panes with "ours" on the left appeared, and file from the other PR being merged on the right.
So I was kind of reviewing both panes and copy-pasted some small sets of lines (import lines that were only in the right side but not in the left side) that were in the right pane into the left ("ours") pane.
Then, I started scrolling down to where the Java methods were, to get an idea how the left and right side lined up, and while I was doing that, I noticed something strange...
In the left ("ours") pane, in one of the smaller methods (maybe 5-6 lines) I noticed something really strange.  1 or 2 of the lines were overwritten with something completely different and one of the lines that should've been there was gone :( !!
I've gone back to look at the commit in Bitbucket, and I can see all the lines that I expected.
So basically, right now some of my local files in Eclipse are not good, so what I wanted to find out is:  Is it possible to get my local files go back to the commit that I made earlier BEFORE I tried to do the merge resolution?
I've been doing some searching and I've seen some posts that say to right click on the commit in Eclipse GIT History and either right click Revert or Checkout?
Would either of those put the local files back to where there were before I started?  And if so, which one?
Also, I've tried to describe what I did as best I can above... From that, is there any idea what I might've done that would cause that one file to get so messed up?
Thanks in advance.  If there is any additional info I can provide I will try.
Jim
P.S. I'll update this post with the link to my previous question from last week in a bit.
EDIT 1:  As mentioned there is only 1 file that had conflicts... So I am wondering:  Could I right click on that 1 file in the unstaged pane in git staging and the click "Replace with HEAD revision"?
Would that replace that one file with the file the version of that file that was just committed (and which is in Bitbucket)?  Also, and then could I right-click the replaced file and try merge tool again?
And could I do that multiple times as long as I did NOT do another commit, correct?

It is unclear to me what you are asking. Could you please shorten your question and provide a minimal reproducible example. Please note that in Git, editing a file in parallel only leads to conflicts if and only if the same or closely located lines have been edited. In contrast to SVN, a commit in Git is a change/difference and not a new version/state. Revert commit creates a new inverse commit, Replace with HEAD revision reverts your local changes of the selected files and a Reset reverts all files to the selected commit.

I'm not sure if i got you right.
But if

Is it possible to get my local files go back to the commit that I made earlier BEFORE I tried to do the merge resolution?

is your main question, than you can discard your merge-attempt by a right klick on the last commit of the branch your merging into in the git history.
And then select Reset Hard(Head, Index, and Working Tree)
